# How can I include custom text inside a file saved from a php form?

Tags: php, html

I'm using this code below that simply takes the name of an artist submitted through a form and saves it as a html file on the server.

```
<?php


if (isset($_GET['artist'])) {
$fileName = $_GET['artist'].".html";
$fileHandler = fopen($fileName, 'w') or die("can't create file");
fclose($fileHandler);
}
?>
```

What I'm trying to work out is how I could possibly add any code within the file before it is saved. That way every time a user adds an artist I can include my template code within the file. Any help would be great :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `fwrite`.

Two things:

1. `file_put_contents` as a whole will be faster.
2. Your design is a **very bad idea**. They can inject a file anywhere on your filesystem, e.g. `artist=../../../../etc/passwd%00` would try to write to `/etc/passwd` (%00 is a NUL byte, which causes fopen to terminate the string in C - unless that's been fixed).

Answer (score 0):

[`fwrite()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php) allows you to write text to the file.

```
if (isset($_GET['artist'])) {
  $fileName = $_GET['artist'].".html";
  $fileHandler = fopen($fileName, 'w') or die("can't create file");
  fwrite($fileHandler, 'your content goes here');
  fclose($fileHandler);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Warning - be very careful about what you write to the filesystem. In your example there is nothing stopping someone from writing to parts of the filesystem that you would never have expected (eg. artist='../index'!).

I sincerely recommend that you think twice about this, and either save content to a database (using appropriate best practices, ie http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) or at least make sure that you limit the characters used in the filename strings (eg. only allow characters A-Z or a-z and '_', for example). It's dangerous and exploitable otherwise, and at the very least you run the risk of your site being defaced or abused.

As others have said - you should be able to write php code to the filesystem with fwrite.